# Shiny flexdashboard that displays the results of a query

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am attempting to create a shiny flexdashboard that displays the results of a SQL query. My code includes selectable parameters for a site, month and year that feed into the query. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to render the query results, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the code:

```
# ---
# title: "Site Dashboard"
# output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
# runtime: shiny
# ---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)

Column {.sidebar}       

selectInput("site", label = "WIM Site",
            choices = c("26","27"),
            selected = "26")

numericInput("month", label = "Month",
             value = 12, min = 1, max = 12, step = 1)

selectInput("year", label = "Year",
            choices = c("2014","2015","2016"),
            selected = "2015")    


Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ### Query Results


db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="N:/TrafMon/WIM/Ian/minWIM.sqlite")

query<-reactive({
  paste("SELECT * FROM", paste("wim",input$site,"_", input$year,
   sep=""),paste("WHERE month =="),input$month, "LIMIT 5")
})


a <- reactive({
  sqldf(query, dbname="N:/TrafMon/WIM/Ian/minWIM.sqlite")
})

query

renderTable(a)
```

I've tried rendering the table with `renderTable(a())`, `renderText(a())`, `renderText(a)`. Nothing appears to work. I should note that running the same query code in Rstudio produces the expected output, so the problem is not with the query.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Would you like to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use `reactive` you need added `()` after ( in all reactives)

like:

`sqldf(query(), dbname="N:/TrafMon/WIM/Ian/minWIM.sqlite")`

```
renderTable(a())
```